# Transform GeoRSS from WGS84 to UTM 33N with ogr2ogr

Tags: ogr2ogr, georss

Is this really not supported or do I have missed something in my code? If it is not possible with ogr2ogr, do you know of any other open source methods to reproject from GeoRSS to GeoRSS or from shp to GeoRSS?

```
srcfile=D:/GIS_DataBase/QGIS_Projects/BIK-Stm/BIK_STAINACH_new.xml
destfile=D:/GIS_DataBase/QGIS_Projects/BIK-Stm/BIK_STAINACH_UTM.xml

ogr2ogr -f "GeoRSS" $destfile -t_srs "EPSG:25833" $srcfile

echo check result:
ogrinfo -al $destfile

$ sh reproject.sh
ERROR 6: For a non GML dialect, only WGS84 SRS is supported
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation of layer georss (use -skipfailures to skip errors)
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SIMPLE GeoRSS format is the default, and it only supports WGS84. You need to specify the GML GEOM_DIALECT if you want to use something other than WGS84. See http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_georss.html for the full details.

Comment: ..where would I put the statement `GEOM_DIALECT=GML` in the ogr2ogr call (if applicable)

Comment: As noted in the GeoRSS page I linked to, its a dataset creation option, so you would use -dsco. http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html may help too.